# Suitescript N/Search Filter by custom sublist line field

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to add a search filter for a custom line item field in a suitelet and it is returning no results.

```
   function getExpenseSearch(soNum){
      log.debug('getExpenseSearch entered')
      log.debug('soNum: ' + soNum)
      var billSearch = search.create({
         type: 'transaction',
         filters: [
         [ 'type', search.Operator.ANYOF , ['VendBill']], 'and',
         ['mainline', search.Operator.IS,['F']], 'and',
         ['custcol_connected_so', search.Operator.ANYOF, [soNum]] ///<=== this is the problem why is it not registering?
         ],
         columns: ['trandate',
                   'tranid',
                   'amount'
         ]
      }).run().getRange({start: 0, end: 100})
      log.debug('return billSearch[0].tranid: ' + billSearch[0].tranid) //<== always undefined

      return billSearch
      }
```

I have isolated the problem to the sublist field
custcol_connected_so is a List field (of sales orders)
soNum is the netsuite internal id of the record

I have already tried the following:

- changed .IS to to .ANYOF
- used TEXT value instead of recID
- hardcoded the correct recID
- used 'expense.custcol_connected_so (and other variations, shot in the dark)
- input different syntax for create filter

In the records browser there is no join table for the vendorBill so I would think just the custcol_connected_so filter should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking another look there are a couple of issues.

Your syntax for getting the tranid is incorrect (or at least not supported) and you would not be able to get the mainline amount with a single query because you are only going to be able to return the line level amount. In the example below you could use ref.id to load the sales order or to do a lookup Fields call:

This works in my account:

```js
require(['N/search'], search=>{
    search.create({
        type:'creditmemo',
        filters:[
            ['mainline', 'is', 'F'], 'AND',
            ['custcol_linked_transaction', 'anyof', [2403605]]
        ], 
        columns:['tranid', 'custcol_linked_transaction']
    }).run().each(ref=>{
        console.log(ref.id, ref.getValue({name:'tranid'}), ref.getValue({name:'custcol_linked_transaction'}));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: So I have been using that syntax for multiple searches retrieving main body data, in the same suitelet, with no issue. I just used this syntax in the problem search and can now retrieve the value, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

If soNum is the visible sales order number you'd need to get the SO's internal id in order to run that search. Consider:

```js
function getExpenseSearch(soNum) {
   log.debug('getExpenseSearch entered')
   log.debug('soNum: ' + soNum)

   var soInternalId = null;
   search.create({
      type: 'salesorder',
      filters: ['tranid', 'is', soNum]
   }).run().each(function(ref) {
      soInternalId = ref.id;
      return false;
   });

   var billSearch = search.create({
      type: 'vendorbill',
      filters: [
         ['mainline', 'is', 'F'], 'and',
         ['custcol_connected_so', 'is', soInternalId] ///<=== this is the problem why is it not registering?
      ],
      columns: ['trandate',
         'tranid',
         'amount'
      ]
   }).run().getRange({
      start: 0,
      end: 100
   })
   log.debug('return billSearch[0].tranid: ' + billSearch[0].tranid) //<== always undefined

   return billSearch
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear bknights but soNum is the internal id. So in my testing the value being passed is 1509.